# ItemRowBinding is missing in package

Tags: java, android, data-binding

I'm trying to use dataBinding using a recyclerView. But I'm not able to get ItemRowBinding in a package. I have no clue what is the problem. I can't import this package :

**import com.main.databinding.databinding.ItemRowBinding;**

**This is my RecycperAdapter:**

```
@NonNull
@Override
public RecylcerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    ItemRowBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate( //ItemRowBinding is missing
            LayoutInflater.from(context),
            R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(binding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ModelClass modelClass = modelClassList.get(position);

    holder.bind(modelClass);
    holder.itemRowBinding.setItemClickListener(this);
}
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ItemRowBinding itemRowBinding;

    public ViewHolder(ItemRowBinding itemRowBinding) {
        super(itemRowBinding.getRoot());
        this.itemRowBinding = itemRowBinding;
    }

    public void bind(Object obj) {
        itemRowBinding.setVariable(BR.modelClass, obj);
        itemRowBinding.executePendingBindings();
    }
}
```

**This is my XML file:**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="@{() -> itemClickListener.cardClicked(model)}"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{model.tittle}"

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<data>

    <variable
        name="model"
        type="com.main.bawmlabu.models.Model" />

    <variable
        name="itemClickListener"
        type="com.main.bawmlabu.models.CustomCliskListener" />
</data>
</layout>
```

All of these seem correct but I don't know where I'm missing the point.

[image]

Comment: Sometime it just need to clean the project form Build\Clean Project

Comment: I notice the layout (R.layout.item_row) like it's not exist, check that first i don't think the problem with the Binding it is in the layout

Comment: I know but it won't change anything.

Comment: Why I can't import this - "import com.main.databinding.databinding.ItemRowBinding;"

Answer (score 0):

Your generated binding class name is RowItemBinding not ItemRowBinding.

```
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_rect_tv_blue"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Viewholder -

```
    public class SampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        RowItemBinding binding;

      
        public SampleViewHolder(@NonNull RowItemBinding itemView) {
            super(itemView.getRoot());
            binding = itemView;

        }
}
```

Comment: I did. Please check the XML code.

Comment: clean code and rebuild project

Comment: do you have ViewHolder implemented, can you show its code?

Comment: check above code, your binding class name was wrong you should call RowItembinding

Comment: It's the same. Can't call it.(RED TAG)